# Could not build wheels since package wheel is not installed

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, python-wheel

I am having this problem with wheels: 'Could not build wheels for ..., since package 'wheel' is not installed.' with several packages and I have no idea what to do since - as you can see in the very end - I have installed the wheel package

I am doing this on Ubuntu 18.04

I will be grateful for any help!

```
mikolajbe@mikolajbe-vb:~/freqtrade$ ./setup.sh --install
/usr/bin/python3.6
using Python 3.6
-------------------------
Installing mandatory dependencies
-------------------------
Debian/Ubuntu detected. Setup for this system in-progress
 This PPA has been removed from public access as part of a protest against the abuse of open-source projects by large companies. For more detail visit the main page here: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

If you are a company and you would like this PPA to continue then let me know your preferred route for contributions and I will arrange something.

If we have already been in contact then ping me your Launchpad ID and I will add you to a private PPA in the meantime.

---

Donate to Python: https://www.python.org/psf/donations/
Donate to Debian: https://www.debian.org/donations
Donate to me: https://ko-fi.com/jonathonf
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                            
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                          
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                             
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                            
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                   
Hit:5 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
autoconf is already the newest version (2.69-11).
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
libtool is already the newest version (2.4.6-2).
make is already the newest version (4.1-9.1ubuntu1).
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu2).
git is already the newest version (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7).
python3.6 is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1).
python3.6-dev is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1).
wget is already the newest version (1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2).
python3.6-venv is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 296 not upgraded.
ta-lib already installed, skipping

----------------------------
Reseting branch and virtual env
----------------------------
- Delete your previous virtual env
- Hard resetting of 'develop' branch.
HEAD is now at e08af1ab Update requirements.txt

-------------------------
Updating your virtual env
-------------------------
pip3 install in-progress. Please wait...
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/2e/df11ea7e23e7e761d484ed3740285a34e38548cf2bad2bed3dd5768ec8b9/pip-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/27/e35e7c6e6a52fab9fcc64fc2b20c6b516eba930bb02b10ace3b38200d3ab/numpy-1.18.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, numpy
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.4 pip-20.1
Collecting ccxt==1.18.119
  Using cached ccxt-1.18.119-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy==1.2.15
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.2.15.tar.gz (5.6 MB)
Collecting python-telegram-bot==11.1.0
  Using cached python_telegram_bot-11.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (326 kB)
Collecting arrow==0.13.0
  Using cached arrow-0.13.0.tar.gz (92 kB)
Collecting cachetools==3.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting requests==2.21.0
  Using cached requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.24.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Collecting wrapt==1.11.0
  Using cached wrapt-1.11.0.tar.gz (27 kB)
Collecting pandas==0.23.4
  Using cached pandas-0.23.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (8.9 MB)
Collecting scikit-learn==0.20.2
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.20.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.4 MB)
Collecting joblib==0.13.0
  Using cached joblib-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (276 kB)
Collecting scipy==1.2.0
  Using cached scipy-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.6 MB)
Collecting jsonschema==2.6.0
  Using cached jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.15.4
  Using cached numpy-1.15.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.9 MB)
Collecting TA-Lib==0.4.17
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz (717 kB)
Collecting tabulate==0.8.2
  Using cached tabulate-0.8.2.tar.gz (45 kB)
Collecting coinmarketcap==5.0.3
  Using cached coinmarketcap-5.0.3.tar.gz (7.0 kB)
Collecting python-rapidjson
  Using cached python_rapidjson-0.9.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting scikit-optimize==0.5.2
  Using cached scikit_optimize-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
Collecting py_find_1st==1.1.3
  Using cached py_find_1st-1.1.3.tar.gz (7.6 kB)
Collecting aiodns==1.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"
  Using cached aiodns-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools>=38.5.1 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (39.0.1)
Collecting certifi>=2018.1.18
  Using cached certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
Collecting yarl==1.1.0; python_version >= "3.5.2"
  Using cached yarl-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (255 kB)
Collecting aiohttp>=3.0.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"
  Using cached aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-2.9.2-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.7 MB)
Collecting future>=0.16.0
  Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2011k
  Using cached pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting requests_cache>=0.4.13
  Using cached requests_cache-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting pycares>=1.0.0
  Using cached pycares-3.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (228 kB)
Collecting multidict>=4.0
  Using cached multidict-4.7.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (148 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5; python_version < "3.7"
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.7.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting idna-ssl>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"
  Using cached idna-ssl-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.4 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8
  Using cached cffi-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (399 kB)
Collecting six>=1.4.1
  Using cached six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Could not build wheels for SQLAlchemy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for arrow, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for wrapt, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for TA-Lib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for tabulate, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for coinmarketcap, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for py-find-1st, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for setuptools, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for future, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for idna-ssl, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, pycares, aiodns, certifi, multidict, idna, yarl, attrs, typing-extensions, idna-ssl, chardet, async-timeout, aiohttp, urllib3, requests, ccxt, SQLAlchemy, six, cryptography, future, python-telegram-bot, python-dateutil, arrow, cachetools, wrapt, numpy, pytz, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, joblib, jsonschema, TA-Lib, tabulate, requests-cache, coinmarketcap, python-rapidjson, scikit-optimize, py-find-1st
    Running setup.py install for idna-ssl ... done
    Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy ... done
    Running setup.py install for future ... done
    Running setup.py install for arrow ... done
    Running setup.py install for wrapt ... done
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.18.4
    Uninstalling numpy-1.18.4:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.18.4
    Running setup.py install for TA-Lib ... done
    Running setup.py install for tabulate ... done
    Running setup.py install for coinmarketcap ... done
    Running setup.py install for py-find-1st ... done
Successfully installed SQLAlchemy-1.2.15 TA-Lib-0.4.17 aiodns-1.1.1 aiohttp-3.6.2 arrow-0.13.0 async-timeout-3.0.1 attrs-19.3.0 cachetools-3.0.0 ccxt-1.18.119 certifi-2020.4.5.1 cffi-1.14.0 chardet-3.0.4 coinmarketcap-5.0.3 cryptography-2.9.2 future-0.18.2 idna-2.8 idna-ssl-1.1.0 joblib-0.13.0 jsonschema-2.6.0 multidict-4.7.5 numpy-1.15.4 pandas-0.23.4 py-find-1st-1.1.3 pycares-3.1.1 pycparser-2.20 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-rapidjson-0.9.1 python-telegram-bot-11.1.0 pytz-2020.1 requests-2.21.0 requests-cache-0.5.2 scikit-learn-0.20.2 scikit-optimize-0.5.2 scipy-1.2.0 six-1.14.0 tabulate-0.8.2 typing-extensions-3.7.4.2 urllib3-1.24.1 wrapt-1.11.0 yarl-1.1.0
Do you want to install dependencies for dev [y/N]? y
Requirement already up-to-date: ccxt==1.18.119 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.18.119)
Requirement already up-to-date: SQLAlchemy==1.2.15 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.2.15)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-telegram-bot==11.1.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (11.1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: arrow==0.13.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.13.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: cachetools==3.0.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (3.0.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests==2.21.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (2.21.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3==1.24.1 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.24.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: wrapt==1.11.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.11.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pandas==0.23.4 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.23.4)
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn==0.20.2 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (0.20.2)
Requirement already up-to-date: joblib==0.13.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (0.13.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy==1.2.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (1.2.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: jsonschema==2.6.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (2.6.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy==1.15.4 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.15.4)
Requirement already up-to-date: TA-Lib==0.4.17 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (0.4.17)
Requirement already up-to-date: tabulate==0.8.2 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (0.8.2)
Requirement already up-to-date: coinmarketcap==5.0.3 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (5.0.3)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-rapidjson in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 18)) (0.9.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-optimize==0.5.2 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 21)) (0.5.2)
Requirement already up-to-date: py_find_1st==1.1.3 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 24)) (1.1.3)
Collecting flake8==3.6.0
  Using cached flake8-3.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
Collecting pytest==4.1.0
  Using cached pytest-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (215 kB)
Collecting pytest-mock==1.10.0
  Using cached pytest_mock-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
Collecting pytest-asyncio==0.10.0
  Using cached pytest_asyncio-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pytest-cov==2.6.1
  Using cached pytest_cov-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools>=38.5.1 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: yarl==1.1.0; python_version >= "3.5.2" in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: aiohttp>=3.0.1; python_version >= "3.5.2" in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: aiodns==1.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.2" in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2018.1.18 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: future>=0.16.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-telegram-bot==11.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cryptography in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-telegram-bot==11.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from arrow==0.13.0->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests==2.21.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests==2.21.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2011k in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas==0.23.4->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests_cache>=0.4.13 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from coinmarketcap==5.0.3->-r requirements.txt (line 17)) (0.5.2)
Collecting pyflakes<2.1.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached pyflakes-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Using cached mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Collecting pycodestyle<2.5.0,>=2.4.0
  Using cached pycodestyle-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting atomicwrites>=1.0
  Using cached atomicwrites-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting more-itertools>=4.0.0
  Using cached more_itertools-8.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting pluggy>=0.7
  Using cached pluggy-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest==4.1.0->-r requirements-dev.txt (line 5)) (1.14.0)
Collecting py>=1.5.0
  Using cached py-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: attrs>=17.4.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest==4.1.0->-r requirements-dev.txt (line 5)) (19.3.0)
Collecting coverage>=4.4
  Using cached coverage-5.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (227 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: multidict>=4.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from yarl==1.1.0; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna-ssl>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.0.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.0.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: typing-extensions>=3.6.5; python_version < "3.7" in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.0.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.7.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycares>=1.0.0 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiodns==1.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt==1.18.119->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography->python-telegram-bot==11.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.14.0)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"
  Using cached importlib_metadata-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycparser in ./.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography->python-telegram-bot==11.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.20)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Using cached zipp-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Could not build wheels for ccxt, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for SQLAlchemy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for python-telegram-bot, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for arrow, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for cachetools, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for requests, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for urllib3, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for wrapt, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for pandas, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for joblib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for scipy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for jsonschema, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for TA-Lib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for tabulate, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for coinmarketcap, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for python-rapidjson, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for scikit-optimize, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for py-find-1st, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for setuptools, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for yarl, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for aiohttp, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for aiodns, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for certifi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for future, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for cryptography, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for python-dateutil, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for idna, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for chardet, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for pytz, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for requests-cache, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for six, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for attrs, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for multidict, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for idna-ssl, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for async-timeout, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for typing-extensions, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for pycares, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for cffi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Could not build wheels for pycparser, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyflakes, mccabe, pycodestyle, flake8, atomicwrites, more-itertools, zipp, importlib-metadata, pluggy, py, pytest, pytest-mock, pytest-asyncio, coverage, pytest-cov
Successfully installed atomicwrites-1.4.0 coverage-5.1 flake8-3.6.0 importlib-metadata-1.6.0 mccabe-0.6.1 more-itertools-8.2.0 pluggy-0.13.1 py-1.8.1 pycodestyle-2.4.0 pyflakes-2.0.0 pytest-4.1.0 pytest-asyncio-0.10.0 pytest-cov-2.6.1 pytest-mock-1.10.0 zipp-3.1.0
pip3 install completed

-------------------------
Generating config file
-------------------------
A config file already exist, do you want to override it [y/N]? y
Starting to generate config.json

Generating General configuration
-------------------------
Max open trades: (Default: 3) 
Stake amount: (Default: 0.05) 
Stake currency: (Default: BTC) 
Fiat currency: (Default: USD) 

Generating exchange config 
------------------------
Exchange API key: 
Exchange API Secret: 

Generating Telegram config
-------------------------
Telegram Token: 
Telegram Chat_id: 

-------------------------
Config file generated
-------------------------
Edit ./config.json to modify Pair and other configurations.

-------------------------
Run the bot !
-------------------------
You can now use the bot by executing 'source .env/bin/activate; python freqtrade/main.py'.
mikolajbe@mikolajbe-vb:~/freqtrade$ pip3 install wheel
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /home/mikolajbe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.34.2)
```

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-wheel`

Comment: `I have installed the wheel package` please show its version and how you checked.

Comment: @greybeard  in the end of the code I enclosed is the way I checked, 
I also checked like this:
'mikolajbe@mikolajbe-vb:~/freqtrade$ wheel version
wheel 0.34.2'

Comment: @RMPR  I used your commend and run installation again - result was the same, couldn't build the wheels

Comment: I wonder if those virtual-env mentions at the beginning are relevant. Have you tried running `source .env/bin/activate` before running `pip3 install wheel`? It looks like maybe your setup.py is using a virtual env, though I'm not an expert.

Comment: Actually, if that's the case and setup is using a virtual env of its own maybe it's best to add the wheel dependency in your setup.py somewhere. But again, not an expert.

Comment: I solved similar problem by just installing wheel with pip install wheel.

Comment: I have wheel installed. That's why I don't know what to do to solve this problem

Comment: Seems like you have a virtualenv for this application. You probably need to install `wheel` to the virtualenv, not the system Python.

Answer (score 127):

You need to install the `wheel` package, like this: `pip install wheel`

Comment: @Vatine: It appears to be a valid answer to me—albeit one that was  asked and answered already in the comments.

Comment: @JeremyCaney The way it's phrased, it's definitely a comment. As an answer, I would expect a different phrasing and more explanation of why it would make a difference.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in my question, I have installed wheel package

Comment: @mikolajbe I got the same problem with freqtrade installation on ubuntu yesterday 
 and in the manual was that you need python3-wheel but after that I had the same error, even though wheel was installed, after pip install wheel everything was good, so just do it

Comment: Worked perfect for me, Thank you!!!!
After wheel have updated dependencies using the `.lock` file, I ran `poetry update` and this solved the problem.
By running `update`, poetry update dependencies, and therefor it's managing to install `python-rapidjson`.

Comment: @GrzegorzWRO can you add clarification to the answer that for some reason, even if `wheel` is already installed, `pip install wheel` says it does nothing but somehow fixes the original problem