# Setting up scipy under other library

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install NiaPy from this location: https://github.com/NiaOrg/NiaPy
The installation process looks to be very easy but after the beginning, I got this error:
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for scipy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

```
Installing collected packages: scipy, numpy, Niapy
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.5.4
    Uninstalling scipy-1.5.4:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.5.4
    Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
```

And the installation process was terminated.
So, if I am right, NiaPy requires some other packages like scipy etc.
I tried to install wheel:

```
python3 -m pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.36.2
```

But the problem isn't solved. After that, I tried reinstalling both scipy and numpy but the same thing is happening. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678445/could-not-build-wheels-since-package-wheel-is-not-installed

Comment: @IronMan Tnx! But that is exactly what I tried. I wrote it in the second code box in my question

Comment: You are not providing enough information to dig deeper into your issue. However, you could try installing the latest release candidate version of NiaPy using "pip install NiaPy==2.0.0rc12".